# UnicodeDecodeError using Django smart_str with European letters

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I am getting the error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 138: ordinal not in range(128)

when I try to do

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

u'{}'.format(smart_str('ø'))
```

but the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.smart_str) says that the default encoding for this function is utf-8 which I thought should include 'ø'. I am using Django 1.11 on Python 2.7. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your python and django version? I tried your code, but it didn't raise error. My python version is `3.7` and django version is `2.1.5`

Comment: Added those details to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726926/unicodedecodeerror-using-django-and-format-strings) I discovered that Python 2.7 (but not Python 3.x) has issues converting between utf-8 and unicode. Who'da thunk it? So I needed to decode my string before formatting it:

```
u'{}'.format(smart_str('ø').decode('utf-8'))
```